# Baixar dados de API que retorna formato JSON dentro de XML

Tags: r, xml, rvest

Estou acessando um site que disponibiliza uma API que retorna os dados no formato JSON, mas os dados estão retornado dentro um código XML no formato abaixo:

```xml
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[arquivo JSON]</string>
```

Como extrair este arquivo JSON de dentro do código XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentar algo assim:

```
    library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "http://site/api/transparencia.asmx/json_frota_veiculos?fbclid=IwAR3YRmwhEGVcePgavCUDwsCmeb_Z4ddgIwTH8Lp5Gv5elTy6fXRixkHFHeE"

page <- read_xml(url) %>% 
xml_text() %>% 
fromJSON()
```